# Python Transparent Image masking

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I have two images of equal size. Both of them have shape (h,w,4) which is 4 channels for RGB and Alpha.

**I would like to put all of the pixels of img2 onto img1 wherever img2's alpha value is greater than zero** (And not translate the transparent parts of img2). How can I achieve this?

I would highly prefer answers that show me how to create a mask for this situation and allows me to simply do: `img1[mask] = img2[mask]`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be super easy. You can make the mask like so:

```
mask = img2[..., 3] > 0
```

Then, like you said, just do:

```
img1[mask] = img2[mask]
```